# Copy columns of tables on web pages

Tags: macos, mac, safari, preview, copy-paste

In PDFs in Preview I can select individual columns of tables by pressing the option key while dragging. This selects individual columns like this:

[image]

However, pressing the option key while dragging in a web page doesn't work and dragging just selects all cells of a table like:

[image]

Is there a way to select individual columns of tables on web pages?

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK opening the HTML page in Chrome, then just use the CopyTables extension in Chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copytables/ekdpkppgmlalfkphpibadldikjimijon?hl=en

Comment: FWIW, CopyTables is now available natively for Safari: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/copytables/id1472937623

Comment: @georg - I would offer that's not what "natively" means.

Answer (score 2):

**WORKAROUND SOLUTION - NOT ACTUAL ANSWER TO THE QUESTION**

I faced the same issue and found the quickest following Google Sheets workaround so far. Please let me know if you find a better way:

**1st STEP:**

Simply Highlight and copy the entire table content from the web page.

[image]

**2nd STEP:**

Open a Google Sheet and paste the clipboard content.

[image]

**3rd STEP:**

Highlight and copy the individual column of your choice.

[image]

Comment: Good effort - I think it would be best to highlight that this is a workaround, as it doesn't really answer the question (else some will downvote this answer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @sfxedit ! Done!

Answer (score 0):

In the Safari website those are (images).
You can not select individual column.

However if you download the Article in PDF format then open with Preview.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/296692096_Waterbirds_in_the_UK_201314_The_Wetland_Bird_Survey

[image]